# Google Analytics: How to add selected events to custom report as metric

Tags: google-analytics

I have custom reports for certain very important pages (URLs) on our website.
The reports use a pagePath REgex filter to only show results from certain pages.

Now my issue:
I want to add a custom event (i.e. how often somebody clicks on a phone link)
The phone-event is working and being tracked.

But How can I add it to this custom report as a metric?
=> show me the number of triggered events for the URLs that match the REGEXP in the selected time-frame...

Answer (score 3):

*I will present a detailed answer to your question first. After that I will also suggest an alternative solution.*

You can add the event to a Goal i.e. you trigger a goal based on your event.
If you are familiar with goals in GA you can set goal values that match the metrics you would like to track.

**This is how:**

First you need to create a goal based on the event you wish to use. I assume that you already measure the event(s). Now go to the Admin section of your GA account. Select your website view. Click Goals to create a new Goal.

In the Goal setup you select "Custom" and click on the Continue button. Now you pick a name for your event. Remember this name because you will need it later. Now pick a Goal slot ID or use the suggested. Next you are going to select the type of action your Goal should use. Select Event and then click Continue.

Now you need to select Event Category, Action, Label or Value based on the event from the phone link click. When that is done you have two options for the value:

1. Use the event value as the Goal Value.
2. Assign a monetary value e.g. 1

I would suggest you go with number 2.

If you have enough event data you can try to click on Verify this Goal. Don't worry if it doesn't show anything yet. It is not uncommon when you have low volume of events.

Click Save. Now your Goal is setup and you need to open your custom report. When you have opened your report you will need to Edit it.

Since you already have setup your pagePath regex filter I will not go into that. Instead you should pick a Metric Groups. In the blue drop down you will now look for the Goal name I asked you to remember. Find it and add it to your metric group.

Pick a suitable Dimension Drilldown e.g. "Page" in the green dropdown.

Almost done. Pick a view for the custom report. You can actually have several views. Finally click Save.

**Alternative solution:**

If you are familiar with segments I would really suggest that you use that instead. You can create a segment with your URL regex in a custom segment and apply that segment to any standard report you like, including the event reports. That way you can evaluate the event you are asking about here, but also other events you may have.

Comment: Can you add instructions to this answer for matching goal values based on regex urls?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller absolutely. I'll get back with instructions+example asap.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume that your custom event is working and you can see tracking data in real time report and behavior report under Events, and you do not want to track this event as goal.

Than you should create filter for that specific event by selecting its category, action or label:

[image: Custom Report Google Analytics Filter Setup for Custom Event]

Answer (score -1):

The metric is 'unique events' - filtered to match the event label for the phone link click

Comment: The system flagged this as a low quality post. Can you add more or explain this better?

Comment: That's the answer.He wants to add it to a custom report as a metric. The appropriate metric is Unique Event, with a filter to match the specific event. It's one sentence because the solution to his problem is very simple.

Comment: Is the filter the normal report-filter? Wont the filter change all other metrics as well?

Comment: I don't think this is the answer to the question.   The question is about a regex filter applied to Google Analytics for URL that is not picking up on events.   This answer doesn't explain how to add events (even unique events) to a filter based on URLs.