# How to set up google analytics custom report?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

See bottom for the tl;dr, the first paragraphs describe the steps I have completed so far.

I have written a script that collects information and pushes it to the dataLayer. In google tag manager interface I have set up two tags alongside with the relevant variables and triggers.

The first tag regards page impression and collects some general page information like name, category etc. I have set the tag manager variables I want to populate and I set the tag trigger to be on DOM ready.

The second tag regards enhanced ecommerce about product impression. I have specified in the tag settings to use the dataLayer (in which I push the ecommerce object according to Google's specifications) instead of custom variables and I have set a custom trigger for the tag, again to be fired on DOM ready, but this time when the url contains "product".

I have enabled preview from google tag manager interface and when I load my page I can see that both events fire as expected. Regaring the page impression tag, I can also verify that my custom variables do get filled with the expected values.

What I have found no success in doing is actually *seeing* the analytics data on my analytics interface. How do I do that? I found [this relevant SO question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/108463/google-analytics-how-to-add-selected-events-to-custom-report-as-metric) and while I followed its steps I was unable to see any data in my custom report.

**tl;dr** I want to see the tag data I sent in a google analytics custom report. Can not figure out how to set it, or if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I think we need a little more detail to answer this - are you sending the data to custom dimensions or metrics, or to the built-in dimensions and metrics? Can you see the data in GA anywhere?

Comment: @Reve The very reason I posted this question was because I do not know how to display the data in the analytics console. I don't know about custom dimensions, I do not know about metrics. I do see the events in the real time though.

Comment: Can you add a couple of screenshots? It would be helpful to see an example of what is in your dataLayer when the event happens, and the settings of your GTM event tag. Also for your page impressions.

Comment: @Reve unfortunately not, as it is not my own site. What did you need screenshots of?

Comment: The details of how you're sending the data to GA - for example, "The first tag... collects some general page information" - how is it doing that, exactly? I have a guess about what needs to happen but right now it's only a guess! I can try to write an answer anyway, but I'd be able to help better if I knew more.

Comment: @Reve I wrote a custom script that collects the data from the DOM, adds them to a Javascript Object according to Google's documentation and pushes it to the dataLayer via `dataLayer.push(myObject)`.

Comment: I am still not clear on what you are trying to do. It sounds like you are trying to add data to the page impression tag, for instance (such as category). Is that true? If so, where are you trying to put it? Which documentation are you referring to in your latest comment?

Comment: @Reve I am referring to this: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce. I have done everything mentioned in this documentation and I dynamically collect the correct data depending on the page. The GTM tags and events are fired correctly and I can see the events fired in my analytics console in the "real time view". What I don't know is how to set up a custom report so I can see that data sent by the enhanced ecommerce events.

Comment: Hm, if you're using all the standard enhanced ecommerce fields you shouldn't need a custom report to see the data. If you have enhanced ecommerce enabled in GA (Admin > View > Ecommerce Settings, turn on the switches for Enable Ecommerce and Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Reporting and name the steps of your checkout funnel), your data should show up in reports in the Conversions > Ecommerce section of the sidebar. Those dimensions and metrics will be available in custom reports as well. The events, though, are just the vehicle that gets the ecommerce data to GA, and don't show it themselves.

Comment: Ran out of comment characters... I understand now what you are talking about - with both of your tags, is it Enhanced Ecommerce data you are trying to see in GA?

Comment: @Reve First of all, thnx for sticking with me, I appreciate your help. I want to see both enhanced ecommerce data and custom events. I searched around and it seems you are correct and the enhanced ecommerce data has predefined reports in the sidebar. I am still a bit confused with the differences between metrics and dimensions though. For example I have a custom event and I push to the dataLayer an object with the event name + event label + event value. How can I see the event label + value in a custom report?

Comment: Happy to help! By "event name" I assume you mean what you use in GTM to determine a custom event has occurred? To see Event Labels and Values you can visit Behavior > Events > Top Events in the sidebar and switch the Primary Dimension from Event Category to Event Label with the little links between the graph and the table. If you aren't seeing your labels there you might need to add an Event Action to the dataLayer object; in past versions of GA tracking code, an Action has been required, and I'm not sure if it is now.

Comment: Quick description of dimensions vs metrics would be: dimensions describe things, metrics measure things. So if you're counting something, you're using a metric; if you're distinguishing different versions of something, you're using a dimension. Value is a metric because you want to be able to add it up and average it across hits or sessions. Anything you don't want GA to add up would be sent as a dimension, even if it's a number; say, sending the current average rating of a page with its pageview. Sending rating as a metric would have GA showing you (rating)*(# pageviews), which isn't helpful!